# Odd behavior when tracking mouse movement on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent

I'm using a simple script to draw a line on a canvas with the mouse. When the user clicks and drags in the canvas, it should draw in that area. The line does get drawn, but it doesn't follow the mouse, and it doesn't seem to be an offset issue. The longer you hold the button down, the further away from the cursor the line goes. It draws more line than I ask it to, and I can't figure out why. For instance, if I start in the center of the canvas and move toward the bottom, the line will reach the bottom long before the cursor. Here's the code I'm using:

```
if(window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

  function init () {

    front_canvas = document.getElementById('front_paint_canvas');
    front_context = front_canvas.getContext('2d');

    tool = new tool_pencil();

    front_canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
    front_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
    front_canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
  }

  function tool_pencil () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev.clientX - 230, ev.clientY - 280);
        tool.started = true;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        context.lineTo(ev.clientX - 230, ev.clientY - 280);
        context.stroke();
      }
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
      }
    };
  }

  function ev_canvas (ev) {
      context = ev.target.getContext('2d');

    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
      func(ev);
    }
  }

  init();

}, false); }
```

How could this even be happening?

Comment: Is 230, 280 the position of your canvas ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the offset to compensate for the positioning.

Comment: This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TCATw/ works perfectly for me, on Chrome. Does the issue reproduce in your browser?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv That seems to also work for me, somehow. Other than the offset, I'm not seeing a difference between yours and mine.

Comment: Well, this http://jsfiddle.net/TCATw/1/ also works for me, so most likely it works for you too. Can you fork my fiddle and add the differences you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was putting the canvas size in the css instead of as an element property. That was causing the canvas to scale instead of simply resizing, which meant it was handling line drawing as relative coordinates instead of absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Your context probably doesn't have the same size than the canvas. To ensure both are aligned, use this

```
front_canvas.width = front_canvas.clientWidth;
front_canvas.height = front_canvas.clientHeight;
```

just before you create the context.

Comment: This seems to cause it to fail completely. No line is drawn with the addition of this code.